# How to move a 3D snake along Bezier curve

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm developing a 3D game of snake in java and using libgdx, but I have no idea how to do a snake follow a bezier curve. How do I calculate the vertice to get the shape of the curve?

Thanks.

Comment: please show us how you're currently moving the snake so we have a referential start point or maybe try another stackoverflow forum https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165521

Comment: I have a vector of vertices (X, Y, Z). The snake must moving only on X and Y axis. And I have also a bezier function returning a vector(x,y) from a t, like this:
vector = bezier(t);
I need something that changes the vertices positions of snake according the bezier curve.

Comment: Update your answer please. Make it as detailed as possible, show us some code and try to be clear about what you have and what you want (I know that can be hard using a foreign language).

Comment: If I get you right you can get vector at current time. So why don't you just copy coordinates from that vectors?

Comment: Because I want the vertices of snake deform and rotate according to position on the Bézier Curve.